# Remove commits from an accidental merge

Tags: git

I have a situation, where I accidentally merged a submodule in the super project. I ran the below command from the super project i.e the location of .gitmodules

```
git pull submodule_dir/submodule_file
```

Ofcourse, now every commit messages from the submodule is integrated in the super project. I can manually remove the files, because they are just in a folder, but how do I remove all the commits ( they are around 9 in total ) and can also be identified. The problem is that rebase would not work, because the commits are spread across. A rebase  for example to HEAD^9 would also remove some of the commits that actually belongs to the superproject.

`git reset`, `git rebase` wont work. because otherwise, I will loose other commits.

`git reset --hard origin/master` is the closest best bet, but it would destroy my local changes that I already commited.

What could be the solution? I have never used cherry pick,, but I am not sure, if I should do it. I wanted to ask before experimenting and make things worse. Something like this and to remove all the culprit commits.

```
commit latest: this consists of all my local changes and they are precious.
commit 
commit
culprit commit
commit
commit 
culprit commit
commit
commit
culprit commit
commit
commit
commit
commit
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-submodule)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think you have misread the problem. nothing to do with submodules

Comment: You can't rebase out a merge commit but it is possible to rebase to a prior commit in one parent of a merge commit.

Comment: you can `git reset --hard ` on your commit before your merge ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen cud u please remove the duplicate tag.

Answer (score 2):

`git reset --soft HEAD~9` will preserve your changes but will remove the commits

> Does not touch the index file or the working tree at all (but resets the head to , just like all modes do). This leaves all your changed files "Changes to be committed", as git status would put it.

[Source](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#git-reset---soft)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command from your super branch.

```
    git reset --hard HEAD~9
```

It will reset last 9 commits and run below command

```
    git log
```

You can see your commits are removed.